# @WithMockKeycloakAuth get accesstoken as bearer String for mockMvc perform Header

Tags: spring-security, keycloak, openid-connect, spring-test, mockmvc

I have one service and Keycloak 11 as Authentication server. Now I want to write tests. To mock the accesstoken, I use @WithMockKeycloakAuth. This works well and I get an unauthorized when I pass a bad role for example. Now I want to document it with spring rest docs the therefor I have to add the acesstoken as header field ( Bearer tokenAsBearerString ). Because of the annotation, the mocked token is added to the SecurityContext and I can extract it before doing the mvc.perform.

```
@Test
    @Order(5)
    @WithMockKeycloakAuth(authorities = "ROLE_owner")
    void createProduct_RealmRoleOwner_HttpStatusCreated() throws Exception {

        SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        KeycloakAuthenticationToken authentication =(KeycloakAuthenticationToken) context.getAuthentication();
        AccessToken token  =  authentication.getAccount().getKeycloakSecurityContext().getToken();
```

The problem is that I need the accesstoken as Bearer string representation. I'm not yet very familiar with the jwt topic but I expected that if I use the mocked acces token and convert it to a jwt format / Base 64 encoded String the header should be correct.

In addition: I'm running a Keycloak container via docker in a seperate network so it is not reachable while I run my automated test. So mocking would be the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

This question was also asked (and answered) [here](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/issues/12) with a little more context.

The code snippet provided above doesn't show that test class is decorated with `@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)`, reason why the security context is not attached to the MockMvc HTTP request (this is normally done by a spring-security filter).

The complete stack trace isn't provided neither, but it's very likely that the exception occurring when filters are enabled is due to JwtDecoder wiring from Keycloak boot lib. `@MockBean JwtDecoder jwtDecoder;` should be enough to fix it.

Finally, it is one of main features of the lib `@WithMockKeycloakAuth` is taken from to skip fetching, decoding and parsing an actual JWT from Keycloak instance. Trying to build an authorization header with valid JWT from mocked spring authentication is ...